# Sign out of all Windows 365 devices (public computers) remotely

Tags: windows, office365, onedrive

I signed in my personal windows 365 (office 365) account in an incognito browser on a public computer. I opened some Excel files from my web onedrive in a desktop app.

[image]

I closed the browser and the app (Excel) and left the computer.

Few days later I used that computer again and saw I was still logged in onedrive. One could see and open all my onedrive files and folders in the Open menue and Recent File list in Excel.

[image]

[image]

I had a hard time to find how to sign out. For all who don't know:
Backstage-->Account--> My Onedrive  Remove

[image]

But if it is not possible for me to have access to this computer again and sign out,

**how can I see a list of devices where I'm logged in and how can I log out of it.**

All of Microsoft Security is in vain, when one can't log out remotely.

Comment: Log into your office account and you should be able to unlink one drive that way . IIRC you can also unlink devices in one drive properties

Comment: @John I have searched like anything, that's why I am asking here. Please guide me where to find it.

Comment: One Drive App.  Settings, Account.  then Unlink.  For One Drive you would have to do this at the public computers you used.   I do  not see any useful option in the Microsoft web log in

Comment: @John If i remember correctly my onedrive was not listed there on that public computer. However I could log out in the Excel app. But what when I have forgotten it. Anybody who uses that computer will have access to my files.

Comment: When you sign in **and leave the *Stay signed in* box checked**, you leave a cookie on the public PC allowing *anyone* to sign in without two-factor authentication. Hopefully, the PC has a setting to erase cookies at the end of session. Also, by checking "Don't ask me again," you've added that PC. Use more caution on public machines.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Here you answered my other question. I shouldn't have asked two questions at the same time. This Problem here comes from opening a onedrive File in Excel desktop, not from the login.

Comment: So several things: 1. A incognito session of a browser is simply a disposable browser session.  2. While you logged performed the authentication of your MS account within the browser, you also logged into Office, while the authentication of your account was scrapped within the browser Office kept your authentication to be used later.  3. "Anybody who uses that computer will have access to my files." - Only if they used the exact same login as you. If that's the case, you should avoid, logging into your account to access your files from within OneDrive and Office.

Comment: You can disassociated a machine from your Microsoft Account from within the device management section of your Microsoft Account.. Your actions created a store credential, for your account, in order to allow you access to your account.  You used a disposable browser session, thinking it wouldn't store your information, incognito browser sessions are often misunderstood.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't find where to do this in my account. This is my question. I have spend countless hours in searching. If you know please let me know. I have a personal subscription not a business account.

Comment: The device might be listed [here](https://account.microsoft.com/devices).  Removing it there would result in the account having to reauthenticate. [Here](https://account.microsoft.com/services/microsoft365/details#install) is every device that has Office installed, since you logged into Office, it pulled and linked any Microsoft 365 subscription you might have to the device.  I would be more careful of authenticating your MA account on shared machines for obvious reasons

Comment: @Ramhound In a few days I have the opportunity to test if removing devices there will do the trick (I tried before with no success, but I will try again). I will let you know.

Comment: I tested it myself on my own devices. In my experience a Retail installation of Office 2019 will become the most current build of Office 365 if you log into your MA account.  This is the reason I suspect the device will be linked to your Office account and it will allow you to remove it.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried with my Android phone. I had the office app installed a few weeks ago (and signed in) but my phone is not showing up in any of the lists you linked. That is strange, because how does Microsoft otherwise know how many devices I use (5 are allowed). So I signed in my account in a browser. Opened a file in Word (not in browser, but in phone app). But still there is no change in the lists of My devices. Should the phone not be listed there?

Comment: @WeAreOne - The second link I provided are devices using an entitlement to your Office access, an Android, wouldn't use one of those entitlements