# Public computer name shows up in office 365 (microsoft 365) account

Tags: windows, office365

Sometimes I use a public computer and sign in my Microsoft 365 account (at office.com). With 2 step verification.
(in a private browser window).
Some questions come:

[image]

[image]

I coudn't see a difference whether I make the check mark or not. Nor if I click "Yes" or "No"

Sometimes when I look in my account I see this:

[image]

These 2 computers are Public computers. My own computer is not shown in this picture but it is there also (3 computers total).

**Why are these computers listed there?**

**What is the USE of it when a computer is in the device list?**

"Find, Repair and manage your device" is written there. Ok, for computers I own, but public computers should not be there. But they are, that is strange to me. And my android phone, where I'm signed in to the Microsoft office app, is not in this list. Why? Please explain.

I removed them a couple of times, but sometimes when I sign in on office.com in a private browser on these computers, they come back to this list.
So what is this used for.

Comment: You have another similar question open. You likely need to visit these computers and sign out there. Uncheck "Stay Signed in"

Comment: Public Computers are / can be dangerous. Go back to each one you used, and completely sign out of Microsoft, Office and One Drive.  If there is a One Drive icon, use settings to unlink the computer. You need to thoroughly clean up.

Comment: @John Im not signed in those computers when I left them.

Comment: You need to back and clean up. I don't know any other way for public computers.

Comment: This should not be a separate question; edit https://superuser.com/questions/1763448/sign-out-of-all-windows-365-devices-public-computers-remotely

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because reposted: https://superuser.com/questions/1763448/sign-out-of-all-windows-365-devices-public-computers-remotely

Comment: @DrMoishePippik these are different questions.

Comment: Also try logging into your Microsoft account and remove these devices

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The other question is about how to log out of Microsoft 365 remotley. This question is about why these computers are in the list and what it is good for that the computers are there.

Comment: @John No problem in removing them. That was not the question.

Comment: If you remove the public computers then Microsoft Apps should not be active on them. I am really not sure what you might have done here.

Comment: @John If I remove them, the onedrive in Excel desktop app is still available. I tried it. This "setting" has no impact on my other question. When I made this picture,  I was completely logged off at the public computers. In this question I mainly want to know what this "setting" in my devices is good for. I want to understand. Not to remove, I want to understand. DrMoishePippik said it is because of a cookie, but I use a private browser, no cookies are stored in private browsers, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use your Microsoft account to sign-in to a
public computer, but it's a very bad idea to leave checked
"Don't ask me again on this device". This means that your account
is now known on that computer and can perhaps be used by hackers.

More seriously, the fact that the computers come back after being
removed from your Microsoft account, this means that your account is
still active on these computers.

You should revisit the public computers you worked on and remove all
traces of your account, as described below.

**Remove Personal Email and Calendar Entries**

- Run *Settings > Accounts*
- Look for Email, calendar and contacts
- For each, scroll down to "Accounts used by other apps"
- Click on your Microsoft email address
- Click Remove - the account will instantly be removed
- Check under "Add an Account", click your email address if it's
  there, then click *Manage > Delete Account*.

**Remove OneDrive Files from Public Computer**

- Right-click the OneDrive icon on the traybar
- Click Settings
- Position to the Account tab
- Select "Choose folders"
- Clear the check boxes for your folders
- Click OK.

For more information with screenshots see the article :
[Remove Personal Email Accounts and OneDrive Files from Public Computers](https://gaylelarson.com/delete-personal-content-from-public-computers/).

Comment: Will the checkmark "Don't ask me again" really have an impact because I use a private browser?!! I'm not logged into that computer automatically, I always need to sign in with 2 step verification in spite of these computers are in the list of my devices. My question was much more what this "setting" in Devices is good for and what impact it has. You say it is not a good idea to use a public computer to sign in windows 365. Why then should Microsoft develop all these online tools?? How would you do if you need to use a public computer?

Comment: The computers come back in the list after I removed them because I signed in on them to my windows 365 again.

Comment: You can still sign-on if you need to, but that requires knowing how to avoid when you leave staying signed-on and how to clean all traces behind. Working on a public computer requires being methodically careful, for your own good.

Comment: I didn't sign in the windows desktop, but in a private browser in office.com, so there are no traces for email and things.

Comment: Good, but the browser interacted with Windows to do its work. Evidently you didn't obliterate all traces, perhaps also in the browser. The  "Don't ask me again on this device" checkmark means that your data is kept as tokens and and your account will be accessed by default the next time someone else goes on office.com. Your data is then protected by the 2 step verification, forcing him to use his own account rather than yours, but this is not healthy.

Comment: ok, I will try again next week, if it is so. For what I experienced now is: no login data was stored because I needed to login in two steps. My login name was not even stored.
On my own computer, these "don't ask me again" question pop up from time to time also (login data is stored, but pop ups come anyway). It seems they don't work (non-private browser). That's why I really don't understand them. That might become a new question one day.

Comment: My main question was what it is good for that these computers are in that list.

Comment: No, it's not good that they're still linked to your account.

Comment: I would suggest using Chrome in Incognito mode, or its equivalent on other browsers, to avoid leaving traces in the browser.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I mean, what is the USE of it when a computer is in the device list like on the picture! "Find, Repair and manage your device" is written there. Ok, for computers I own, but public computers should not be there. But they are, that is strange to me. I used Chrome incognito on the public computers. I also will update my question.

Comment: Why is it done this way should be asked of Microsoft, I can't know why they did it this way. Not all decisions by Microsoft developers make sense. You have to work with what you have.